# How do I get the benefits of async python?

Tags: python, asynchronous

I have read through the docs and the RealPython article for the asyncio package in the python standard library.

When you call an async function you are returned a python co-routine. So my question is do I have to manually run the co-routine, using the create_task() function from asyncio, to get performance benefits?

I have done some quick experimenting and here are my findings:

If I have four functions (1 sync and 3 async) as described below:

```
def syncFunc():
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(3)
    end_time = time.time()
    print("difference between start and end on sync is: ", end_time - start_time)
```

```
async def asyncSleeper():
    await asyncio.sleep(1) #this could be awaiting a db call or another time consuming method
```

```
async def asyncCallerWithoutTasks():
    start_time = time.time()
    await asyncSleeper()
    await asyncSleeper()
    await asyncSleeper()
    end_time = time.time()
    print("difference between start and end on async without tasks is: ", end_time - start_time)
```

```
async def asyncCallerWithTasks():
    task1 = asyncio.create_task(asyncSleeper())
    task2 = asyncio.create_task(asyncSleeper())
    task3 = asyncio.create_task(asyncSleeper())
    start_time = time.time()
    await task1
    await task2
    await task3
    end_time = time.time()
    print("difference between start and end on async with tasks is: ", end_time - start_time)
```

Then I can run these using:

```
syncFunc()
asyncio.run(asyncCallerWithTasks())
asyncio.run(asyncCallerWithoutTasks())
```

And I get the following output

> difference between start and end on sync is:  3.003000259399414

> difference between start and end on async with tasks is:  1.0009641647338867

> difference between start and end on async without tasks is:  3.0032503604888916

It seems to me that I have to manually set the co-routine to run to get the performance benefits. Is this the correct conclusion or am I doing something stupid here? If yes, is this something async frameworks such as starlette and fastAPI do in the background?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.create_task "and schedule its execution". See the examples in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html

Comment: I read through the docs prior to posting and they discuss the create_task() function. But this is not shown in docs for async libraries such as FastAPI or tourtoise ORM. I was wondering if you must manually create tasks to get performance benefits and if so is it something I should be doing while using these async frameworks.

Comment: there's no performance gains involved. In the first case, they run in parallel, in the second they run one by one.

Comment: In a real world application running tasks in parallel brings a performance boost in terms of time. My question was, if the create_task() function must be used to schedule a task to be run asynchronously is it something i should be doing when using async enabled frameworks, or do they do it in the background.